Is there a way to view all IP addresses sending requests to my website on Cloudflare?
I am trying to mitigate a DDOS attack. Is there a way for me to get a live view or some log of IP addresses sending requests to my website?

The answer below is correct, but if you are in the middle of a DDOS attack you should at least be able to see the IP addresses sending the most traffic to your site currently in the Cloudflare analytics page in your account.

While Cloudflare itself doesn't provide a direct list of all IP addresses sending requests to your site (unless you're on an Enterprise plan), you can still gather this information by logging the CF-Connecting-IP header on your server. This method ensures you have access to the original client IP addresses and can analyze them as needed.
